# What is the meaning of "hot"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, meaning, word-meaning

I find so many people saying

> You look **hot**!

I am a bit confused about this. What does this word stand for? I mean, is this a feeling? Or is this an expression? Or is this a look factor?

Can anybody please explain this?

Comment: See http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/hot, under 7a.

Comment: In this context, depending if it is a woman or man. You got the answer in the look factor.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the last comment.  Both men and women can be described with *hot* meaning "very warm" or *hot* as an informal term meaning "sexually attractive".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *hot* has many meanings and out of those, one is *sexually attractive.*

> [hot (#22)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/HOT) - sexually attractive

Simply, *you look hot* means you look *sexually attractive*.

**Though not the part of answer but maybe useful:** My friend asked me whether to use *hot* or *cool* for a girl he liked! The difference is you call someone *hot* when they are sexually attractive, and call someone *cool* when they are mentally calm (under any stress!).

So I answered use *she's hot* when you are talking about her body or physique and use *she's cool* when you are specific about her mental calmness.

But then *a cool chic hot* or *hot chic cool!* leaves good tingling question. :)